# can't log Hibernate queries log4j

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, log4j

I am trying to log hibernate queries into a webapp specific log file.
I can log any message but I am still unable to log hibernate queries.
Them are being logged inside the `server.log`, even in a different file, but I need an app-specific log for each app running on the same server.
I am using `log4j 1.2`, I am able to create the log files, to log every information passed to console but hibernate queries.
Inside a `database.properties` file I found the `hibernate.show_sql=true` that is responsible for the logging output in console.
This is the kind of console's logging output I refer:

> 16:10:35,827 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Hibernate: select [...](here is outputted the correct query passed, with the `?` of the prepared statement)

Anyway, what I need is to log that output.
I tried different `log4j.xml` settings, but still with no success, it creates log files but does not log those outputs.
Here is the current setting, that is logging everything inside the same file, when I will be able to log even those information I will go on separating the logs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd" >
<log4j:configuration>
<appender name="mainFileAppender2" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
   <param name="append" value="false" />
   <param name="maxFileSize" value="100MB" />
   <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="50" />
    <param name="File" value="${webapp.root}/WEB-INF/logs/mainCORE.log"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p %c{1}:%L %m %n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="journaldev-hibernate2" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="${webapp.root}/WEB-INF/logs/hib-queriesCORE.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="false"/><!--value="true" /-->
    <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="200MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="50" />

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %d{Z} [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
<root>
    <priority value="debug"></priority>
<!--    <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>  -->
    <appender-ref ref="mainFileAppender2"/>
</root>
```

This configuration logs everything but those outputs. In the `server.log` are logged as follows:

> 16:10:35,827 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Hibernate: select [...](rest of the query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure the logger for the following categories:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

The first one will log the SQL-Statement (with ? for parameter values), the second one will print those parameter values if you need them.

So something like this should do the trick in your case:

```
<category name="org.hibernate.SQL">
    <appender-ref ref="journaldev-hibernate2"/>
   <priority value="DEBUG"/>
</category>

<category name="org.hibernate.type">
   <appender-ref ref="journaldev-hibernate2"/>
   <priority value="TRACE"/>
</category>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this way; Anyway it also extracts the values extracted from the query

```
log = ${jboss.server.log.dir}/log/

#Loggers
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FILE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL = DEBUG, HIBERNATE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type = TRACE, HIBERNATE

#Appenders
# Main appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/main.log
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c{1}:%L %m %n
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern=dd-MM-yyyy
# Hibernate queries appender
log4j.appender.HIBERNATE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.HIBERNATE.File=${log}/hib-queries.log
log4j.appender.HIBERNATE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.HIBERNATE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %d{Z} [%t] %-5p     (%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.HIBERNATE.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.HIBERNATE.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.HIBERNATE.Append=true
log4j.appender.HIBERNATE.DatePattern=dd-MM-yyyy
```